# How to disable a user from firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, firebase-authentication

In the firebase API

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users
```

we can delete users, but how could we prevent users from simply registering again, in the GUI for firebase we have the option to disable users , how could we do this in the program, for example if we are building a admin panel that checks posts for a listing site that have been reported, and we want to disable the creator or the reporter for spamming as part of availiable actions.

Thanks.

I develop in react if that changes the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent the user from re-registering, you should **disable** account instead of deleting it. This will prevent the user from signing in again, and from refreshing their ID token. If you want to do this programmatically, have a look at [updating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) with the Admin SDKs. For example, in Node.js it'd be:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, { disabled: true })
```

---

Keep in mind however that even after disabling the account, their existing ID token will remain valid until it expires (typically within an hour), and cannot be revoked. If you want to prevent them from posting in the meantime, you'll **also** want to keep a list of blacklisted/blocked UIDs somewhere, and check against that list before allowing them to write/access the data.

Comment: yes, but in the documentation I could only find ways to delete the user, the only way to disable is from the GUI on firebase console, how can I access that option in code is my current problem

Comment: Use the Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Comment: can I do this on the react front end? It is using node right, would that be an issue? As  I have all my firebase logic already in the front end ( express is written on node )

Comment: Nope. You can't disable an account from the client-side code. That would be a huge abuse vector. If you want to call this from a client, you will have to create a wrapper around the Admin SDK, and then expose that in a custom endpoint (either on a server you controle, or through Cloud Functions). Be sure to check if the caller is authorized to disable accounts in that code though, otherwise you open yuorself up to abuse.

Comment: I am thinking of setting up a post route and calling the admin function, the email of the caller has to be my email , so nobody else can successfully call that post request.

Comment: How will you pass and then verify that email address. If it's through the ID token, then that's indeed a secure way to test this *as long as you also check if the email address is verified*. Otherwise I'm not completely certain, and I'd sooner embed the UID into the code as an identity check.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to programmatically disable a user from the frontend of your app.  You will need a backend, and use the Firebase Admin SDK to [update the user account to become disabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).  The API is [updateUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#updateuser).

Answer (score 0):

Well they can always register again (in case the website is public/ not invite-only), with completely different credentials.

You can do a matching of the new data and existing blocked users, and if it matches above a threshold, flag them.

And you can improve your reporting, the faster you detect a user who should be blocked, the better.

Comment: right but the same email should not be allowed, and we can also set the user to have to be verified email, so its hard for them , it also sends a clear message that will work for 99% of people...

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I'm super familiar with Firebase but ill try and help (can't hurt).

Have you tried to blacklist the IP of the user in question?

Hope I helped :)

Have a good day!

Comment: this is really interesting, do you have any tested methods you have used to do this? I have never done this.

Comment: There is no IP blacklisting for Firebase Auth.